# How to create a standart mvp for kivy application using .kv and .py?

Tags: python, kivy

It seems like people love to use .kv, I can understand but when you have to automatize widget creation, you are limited with .kv format.

I am trying to use .kv and .py to create simple mvp application with toolbar and screen management but I'm stuck with problems I don't understand like this one:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

KV = '''
Screen:

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "MDNavigationDrawer"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    NavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height

        MyScreenManager:

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
'''


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        screen = RandomScreen(name="1")
        #self.add_widget()
        self.switch_to(screen)

class RandomScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Hello world'))


class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

KV = '''
Screen:

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "MDNavigationDrawer"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    NavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height

        MyScreenManager:

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
'''


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        screen = RandomScreen(name="1")
        #self.add_widget()
        self.switch_to(screen)

class RandomScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello world'))


class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

I only change one line, trying to show a label or a button. When I try to show the Label, I can't see it. When I'm doing EXACTLY the same for a Button, I see a button that takes all the space and there is no toolbar anymore !

What is that ??? I'm used to work with tkinter where everything is logical and now I'm lost. :/
Is there a light in the dark path of kivy ?

Answer (score 1):

When creating a button, you need to specify its size to prevent that happening. By default it takes the entire screen.

```
class RandomScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Hello world', size_hint=(.2, .2))
```